# NSMutableArray can't get values from array for objectForKey

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xml-parsing

im parsing xml file, when parser ends parsing connection starts and suppose to get links from array; there is the code: The problem is i think with String "link". NSLog shows that "link" is empty.

```
for (int i=0; i<[imagesArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString *link = [[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"link"];
    NSURLRequest *imageRequest= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]
                                                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                             timeoutInterval:30.0];
    NSURLConnection *imageConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:imageRequest delegate:self];

    if (imageConnection)
    {
        NSLog(@"Counter: %i",i);
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
    [imageConnection start];
    NSLog(@"source", link);
}
```

Thank you for any anwsers and tips.

Comment: Show the code that creates and fills `imagesArray`

Comment: And when is receivedData used? Looks like a leak without purpose to me.

Comment: @C0deH4cker Presumably `receivedData` is an instance variable and will be used by the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol delegate methods as the requested data loads in the background on the runloop.

Comment: However, creating a new `NSMutableData` object and assigning it to `receivedData` each time through the loop is definitely a memory leak, assuming the `imagesArray` contains more than one image.  The posted code doesn't appear to have any way to distinguish between the multiple asynchronous downloads that could be started.

Comment: I'd suggest using the ASIHTTP library instead of NSURL. Its a lot faster, efficient and has a number of extra features such as asynchronous loading